# Странная логика относительных ссылок

Tags: php, веб-программирование

На локальном сервере есть следующая структура папок:

--Components

------Router.php

--config

------routes.php

Файл **Router.php**

```
<?php

class Router
{
    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->routes = include('../config/routes.php');
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Файл **routes.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    'news' => 'news/index',
    'products' => 'product/list',
);
```

В index.php я просто создаю экземпляр класса Router. И появляется следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если же я путь к файлу routes.php напишу так - include('config/routes.php') то все работает, но почему? Ведь для того, чтобы подключить этот файл, нам нужно выйти на один уровень выше, а там уже выбрать папку config и т. д.

Comment: Относительные пути работают относительно текущей рабочей директории, а не текущего файла. Используйте автозагрузчик и абсолютные пути.

Comment: В таких случаях указывайте относительно корневой директории . Предположем папки  `Components` и `config` Находятся в корне сайта,то вот так   `$this->routes = include('/config/routes.php');`в вашем случае они лежат в корне.Вот и сработало :)

Comment: @etki а рабочая директория это всегда корень сайта получается? И в какой бы папке не лежал файл, то относительные ссылки будут без ../ таких элементов? Про автозагрузчик не слышал, т. к. совсем недавно заинтересовался веб-разработкой, почитаю.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan насколько мне известно, на локальном сервере нельзя указывать такие ссылки, я так пробовал.

Comment: Это что угодно в зависимости от сервака, поэтому используйте абсолютные пути.

Comment: Конечно это чушь полная что нельзя.Можно и даже нужно.При абсолютном `path` На сервере каждый раз происходит `connect` и `disconnect` что не оптимально.А при относительных путях иначе.Макс. Число одновременных постоянных подключений по умолчанию для каждого сервера / прокси Смотреть тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/6120970

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan а если например завести константу со значением dirname(__FILE__) и к ней клеить ссылки типа /components/Router.php и т. д., является ли это хорошим решением? P. S. Подсмотрел в одном видеоуроке

Comment: Конечно верно ведь константа содержит относительный путь.Только вот константу надо создавать в корне чтоб отсчет шел от него.

Comment: Понятно. Большое спасибо всем за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дабы нe оставить вопрос без ответа отвечаю.

Это произошло из за того что путь высчитался относительно того файла где был вызван `class Router` А не того где он был декларирован.

> Но если же я путь к файлу routes.php напишу так -
>   include('config/routes.php')  то все работает

Работает потому что путь был указан относительно корня сайта где папка `config` и лежала.

**Совет :** Всегда указывайте полный путь к ресурсу начиная с корня сайта.